# How to access Windows Event Log in terminated Elastic Beanstalk instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have a ASP.NET MVC web application that is deployed to elastic beanstalk. There is an issue that is causing an instance to be identified as unhealthy and terminated. I suspect there's some information in the windows event logs that is going to help me diagnose the issue but once the instance is terminated, the logs are gone.

Any ideas how we could preserve the instance or the logs so that we can have a look at the windows event log?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this? The only solution I could think of is to set up a new *temporary* environment with a single instance, using the current application version, setting the deployment policy to "all at once," and then deploying the new version. The single instance is then preserved even if deployment fails, so you can check the logs. It worked for me, but it's quite cumbersome.

Comment: Off instance logging is the only option